# Why does php only sometimes have a dedicated function for setting an ini parameter?

Tags: php

To set e.g. error reporting, you can use EITHER `error_reporting($X)` OR `set_ini('error_reporting', $X)`. But with e.g. error displaying, you can ONLY use `set_ini('display_errors', $Y)`.

Is there any rhyme or reason to predict when a dedicated function will be available to change ini settings, or is it just haphazard historical happenstance?

(I ask because I want to develop a mental model as to when to use one or the other.)

Comment: if you look at how functions are named, and what order the arguments are accepted in, I’m of the opinion that pretty much all of PHP is luck of the draw :/

Answer (score 0):

I'd dare to say it's historical happenstance.

PHP has a number of such inconsistencies, part of which are listed on [PHP Sadness](http://www.phpsadness.com/). After using PHP for a few years now, my experience is that it's best to have a good IDE rather than trying to remember such things. PhpStorm for example has an auto complete for the parameters of `ini_set()`.

In that particular case, stick with `ini_set()` for consistency because that works for all ini options.